# PROC HTTP SAS Macro issue

Tags: sas, openai-api

I'm using a macro that allows you to prompt CHAT-GPT 3.5 (or trying to at least) within a SAS environment. Here is the code.

```
   options mprint mlogic symbolgen;
```

Obviously not going to show you my API-Key (Fake example provided) but the code works fine outside of being wrapped in a macro but when I run it inside a macro I get this error.

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE resolves to 404
 MLOGIC(CHATGPT):  %IF condition (&SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE. NE 200) is TRUE
 MLOGIC(CHATGPT):  %PUT An error occurred. HTTP &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE.: &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_PHRASE
 SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE resolves to 404
 SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_PHRASE resolves to Not Found
 An error occurred. HTTP 404: Not Found
 MLOGIC(CHATGPT):  %ABORT 
 ERROR: Execution terminated by an %ABORT statement.
```

Is it something to do with the headers authorisation statement in PROC HTTP?. Here is the code outside of the macro.

```
    %let api_key= ; 
    %let question = %str(%"sas code to transpose data%");
    %let question = %str(%"debug 'proc print data=mydf; vars myvar; run;' %");
    
    /* Body of the POST request */
    filename in temp;
    data _null_;
    file in;
    put;
    put "{";
    put  '"model": "gpt-3.5-turbo", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": '"&question }]";
    put "}";
    run;
```

Comment: Run the macro with MPRINT option on.  Copy the generated SAS code into the editor (and clean up to remove the MPRINT() prefix) and try running it.  Compare the generated code to the code you ran without the macro (and without macro variables).

Comment: Check what you actually wrote to the IN fileref using that data step.  You might want to use SYMGET() function to retrieve the value of the macro variable instead of trying resolve it so that what you write to the full will not be processed by the macro processor.

Comment: @Tom Yeah it's weird "bearer &api key." and it seems to follow correct syntax and resolves to my api key correctly but I still get the error.Where would you place the symget () function instead?

Comment: What step is actually failing? Can you write the PROC HTTP call without macro code and macro variables and get it to work?

Comment: @Tom I've added the code outside of the macro. Where it references &api_key. if i just enter the api key it works fine too

Comment: Hardcode the API_KEY in the macro definition and try again. If it still fails then the API_KEY is not the problem.  Compare the IN file made by the macro to the version of the IN file you used that worked.  If it does fail then perhaps in your macro call you added macro quoting to the value passed to API_KEY, Try wrapping the HEADERS statement in a %UNQUOTE() function call to remove the macro quoting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a data step to write the value of a macro variable to a text file it is probably best to first get the value from the macro variable into an actual variable. (Note: Dataset variables can only hold 32K bytes and macro variables can hold 64K bytes.)  This will mean that the macro does not need to worry about macro quoting the value to use it. So if the text includes & or % characters the macro processor will not try to resolve the references.

```
data _null_;
  file in;
  length text $32767;
  text=symget('text');
  put '{"model": "gpt-3.5", "messages": [{"role": "user", "content": ' 
      text :$quote. '}]}'
  ;
run;
```

If you want to generate the AUTHORIZATION headername value in the PROC HTTP call then perhaps it is better to parameterize the macro to expect the full value, instead of just part of the value. So include the text Bearer (if that is required) in the macro call.

```
%macro chatgpt(authorization= ......);
   ...

headers "Authorization" = &authorization. ;
   ...
```

And then when calling the macro pass the authorization value, including the quotes.  Again if the value might include macro triggers like & or % that you don't want the macro processor to modify you can enclose the string in single quotes in the macro call.

```
%chatgpt(authorization='Bearer xxxxxx',......);
```

Comment: I tried both but no luck (I've added a fake example of the style and length of the key). Would PROC PWENCODE work?

Comment: Some optimizations you can make to simplify: use oauth_bearer option on PROC HTTP instead of the HEADERS statement (see doc for details), and use the jsonpp() function in a DATA step to "pretty print" your JSON response (again, see SAS doc for that function). Also, the IN= option on PROC HTTP *can* take a literal string (instead of a fileref) if that makes the work easier.

Comment: Another tip: use the DEBUG L:EVEL=3; statement in PROC HTTP and you will get lots of verbose output that might provide more info.

Comment: PROC PWENCODE isn't for this case. That encodes passwords that SAS will decode before sending on to database connections or data set passwords, but it's not for sending to APIs in PROC HTTP.

Comment: Thanks both. The DEBUG LEVEL= 3 statement helped me greatly to figure out where the issue was.